# AngularJS Sharing Directive Scopes and Iterating Over Values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive who gets it values from a child directive and that populates the fields in the view. An example:

```
app.directive('directive1',function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope:{posts :'='},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.posts = {};
        }
    };
});


app.directive('directive2',function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
           link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            element.bind('click', function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  scope.posts = {
                     '1' : {'title' : 'Cat in Hat'},
                     '2' : {'title' : 'Boat In Like'}
                  };
            });
        }
    };
})
```

HTML

```
<div directive1>
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts track by $index" class="item"><div ng-include="\'/templates/post.html\'"></div>

     <div directive2>Load More Posts</div>
</div>
```

The purpose of this example is to load more posts into directive1 scope is when directive2 is clicked. The problem is, I am getting this error:

```
[$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'directive1' is non-assignable!
```

What is causing this and how should I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to have directive2 `require` directive1 so it can communicate with the directive1 controller.  This allows directive1 to own `posts`, as you have in your example while enabling directive2 to add to it giving us nice separation of responsibilities.

So we'd add this to directive2

```
 require: "^directive1",
```

Then on directive1 we add a controller with a setter method (`addPosts`) using `extend` to add new posts as they come in and then putting the newly merged object on to the scope (using $apply since we're triggering this through a click event:

```
  controller: function($scope){
     var posts = {'0' : {'title' : "Oh the Places Youll Go"}};
     this.addPosts = function($scope,newPosts) { 
        angular.extend(posts,newPosts);
        $scope.$apply(function() {
           $scope.posts = posts;
       });
```

Then we can access directive1's controller by adding it as a parameter to your link:

```
 link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {...}
```

and finally calling `addPosts` from directive 2:

```
  var newPosts = {
     '1' : {'title' : 'Cat in Hat'},
     '2' : {'title' : 'Boat In Like'}
  };
  controller.addPosts(scope,newPosts);
```

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dggp6/